# Show an EmptyView on a ListView bound to a Custom Adapter when filter returns an empty set

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a `ListView` bound to a custom `Adapter` (not a ListActivity) that has `TextFilterEnabled` set to `true`.

Is it possible to have an EmptyView to show when the TextFilter returns an empty set? Note that I'm *not* asking how to set an `EmptyView` when the adapter is empty. I'm asking how to set an `EmptyView` when the text filter returns an empty set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, when you get the count as 0 show the EmptyView or else hide it

```
myAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchText, new Filter.FilterListener() {
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        //handle the visibility here
    }
}
```

Comment: Toggling the Visibility state of the ListView to Gone or Invisible just makes the listview invisible.

I made sure that the EmptyView is set to the ListView by hardcoding an emptyset.

Comment: @Ian You need to have a separate control for EmptyView